# Layout not displaying correct when using ListFragment to display a list of items

Tags: android, android-layout

Android Studio 0.8.10

I am using a ListFragment to display images and text. However, for some reason there is a lot of space between each record.
One record would consist of a image, title. The next one should follow on from there. However, there is a large space between each one, and I have to scroll down to get to the next one. The LinearLayout height is wrapped by the content.

The photos and titles should follow on from each other, there should be no space.

This is my layout that will be displayed in the ListFragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundlist"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:contentDescription="Picture of newsfeed"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ivImage"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My getView function, but I don't see a problem here, all the data is retrieved ok:

```
private class NewsFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsFeed> {
        public NewsFeedAdapter(ArrayList<NewsFeed> newsFeedArrayList) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, newsFeedArrayList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_listfott, null);
            }

            NewsFeed newsFeed = getItem(position);
            mIvImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            mTvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), newsFeed.getImage());
            mIvImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            mTvTitle.setText(newsFeed.getTitle());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

This is the pictures of me scrolling to the next record:
[image]

The next one has a lot of space and have to scroll down to see it.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried "android:layout_alignParentTop = true" on the RelativeLayout that contains the imageView and TextView ?

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi RelativeLayout doesn't contain that property (android:layout_alignParentTop="true"). However, I did add it to the LinearLayout, and it didn't work. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: stupid check, but is the text trimmed? maybe it includes some crs at the end. your layout seems ok, however the relativelayout is totally redundant, i'd put the imageview and the textview into the linearlayout, or better yet, use only a textview and assign the image as the top compound drawable (textviews can contain images on top,bottom,left and right). this way your list will be much more efficient.

Comment: @rupps, I found out what the problem was, but not sure how I can solve it. What I did was removed everything and starting putting it back again. Still had the same problem, so I removed the background from the LinearLayout. Then it starting working as normal. When I set the background back again, I get the same problem. For some reason the background is the problem. Not sure why, but I need this background.

Comment: I know what the problem is. The background I am using is 640x1136 so even if the content is less than that it won't wrap so I am left with the extra that just becomes a large space to scroll through. I am trying to work out what to do about this.

Comment: I'd recommend you to avoid using such a big background for a list element!! It will be a performance hog. If possible at all, don't use any background, use the background in the ListView or the containing root layout. Also, take into account what I posted in the former comments warning about most of the layout being redundant. Remember ViewGroups (Layouts that contain views) are not the lightest objects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scaled down the actual size of the background image, as it was too large.